# IE9, showModalDialog() and window.close() - quirks with compatibility view

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, cross-browser

I have an ASP.NET 3.5 web site project. In it there exists a page (A); within this page there is an `<iframe>` that loads another page (B). From B, a modal dialog is launched through this function:

```
function ShowDialogLookup(anchorDiv) {
    // anchorDiv is div element with some data properties
    var result = window.showModalDialog($(anchorDiv).data('popup-url'), window, "dialogHeight: 300px; dialogWidth: 500px");
    return false;
}
```

*Disclaimer: I wish a thousand times over I could rewrite this to use a jQuery Dialog in modal mode, but I'm only responsible for getting it to work in IE9. So with that said...*

In this popup, the page that is displayed contains an "OK" and a "Cancel" button. The "Cancel" button is simply:

```
<button class="lookup-cancel">Cancel</button>
```

It is assigned an event to close the modal dialog:

```
$('.lookup-cancel').button().click(function() {
    window.close();
});
```

In IE9, **non-compatibility-view mode**, clicking the button causes two things to happen:

1. The modal dialog closes, but
2. A second, full-frame window is launched using the same URL as the modal dialog.

The "Cancel" button within the full window now works properly, when it's no longer contained within a modal dialog window, but whatever prompted IE to launch it is unexpected behavior.

In IE9, **with compatibility-view mode enabled**, clicking the button does exactly what it's supposed to.

- Have I done something jQuery or IE-wise that breaks in IE9 that would have worked in IE 6, 7, or 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got lucky on this one. IE9 apparently cares about the `type` of the `<button>`. In this case, IE9 treats it as a submit button. The act of "submitting" was causing a separate page to load outside of the modal dialog.

Changing the button to:

```
<button type="button" class="lookup-cancel">Cancel</button>
```

solved the issue.